# iPhone SDK: custom buttons in TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm using custom buttons in Table view and it works good for me:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UIImage *detailsButtonImage;
     UIButton *detailsButton;

     NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     }

     //populate cells with array elements
     cell.textLabel.text = [itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     //a custom button
     detailsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     detailsButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"details.png"];
     [detailsButton setBackgroundImage:detailsButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     detailsButton.frame = CGRectMake(275, 10, 20, 22);

      //which cell was tapped?
     [detailsButton setTag:[itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     [detailsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:detailsButton];
      return cell;
 }

//showing details of selected item
- (void) showDetails:(id)sender
{  
    AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
    anotherViewController.title = [sender tag];
    anotherViewController.itemDescription = [itemsDescriptions objectAtIndex:[itemsArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:[sender tag]]]; 

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    [anotherViewController release];
}
```

I'm curious if there is another way of sending a cell identifier to AnotherViewController except setting a tag.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are want showDetails to know which button pushed it.    I think the way you are doing it is fine, but if you wanted you could have a function

- (void) showDetails:(id)sender withObject:(id)object;

and call that with your button rather than just showDetails:(id)sender;  I am inferring that your objects are strings from what you are doing, so it could be

- (void) showDetails:(id)sender withString:(NSString *)string;

But honestly the way you are doing it right now is fine, why change?

Comment: I've heard "setTag" could be replaced with sending an object through button target but I'm puzzled because there is already one target set.