# TableView CustomCell UIButton ISSUE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am using a customCell for my tableView.The CustomCell Contains UIButton.And i want to assign an action with this button.

BeginingCell.h holds declination for the UIButton as :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BeginingCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UIButton *ansBtn1; 
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *ansBtn1;

@end
```

And the implementation is :

```
//
//  BeginingCell.m
//  customCells
//

#import "BeginingCell.h"    

@implementation BeginingCell

///########### Synthesize ///###########

@synthesize ansBtn1;

///########### Factory ///###########

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}

///########### End Factory ///###########

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I am using this CustomCell in a tableView.I want a response from the button Click.How can i assign a button action for my customCell Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(myButtonAction:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton setTitle:@"Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(buttonFrame);
[self addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: what is the buttonFrame here?

Comment: the frame you want to place the button in. It specifies the coordinates for the rect eg: 0,0,20,20

Comment: i am not using any frame here.BeginingCell is my customButton Class.And i am trying the get a response from it in my tableView where i am showing my customCell of beginingCell

Comment: It just specifies where you want the button you can give the value according to your needs

Comment: i don't have any problem with the button placement.I need to know how a UIbutton Responds from a customCell.Anyway where do you suggest to put those codes?In the beginingCell class or TableView class?

Comment: In your case cellForRowAtIndexPath: change the code as [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton]; Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486434/iphone-sdk-custom-buttons-in-tableview for further info

Comment: i tried this one.I think problem is i am loading my customCell from BeginingCell.xib.And it's containing the controls inside a contentView.I am not even getting any response from the BeginingCell.Can you please guide me a proper way step by step?

Comment: :D...finally it's done...actually there was a UIView under the controls...so it wasn't responding...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making your button an IBOutlet and trying to wrire it to ur IBAction, just wire it manualy in `-(void)viewDidLoad` like so:

```
[ansBtn1 addTarget:self action: @selector(myActionMethod:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: where should i put this code?In the customCell implementation?or TableView implementation?

Comment: In the implimentation for your table view. When you create the cell that u want to contain the button, you add the button as a subview, and then use addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Comment: I am using a a BeginingCell.xib in the tableView.And setting the titles in the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { cell.Option4.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option4"];} how can i add subView then?

Comment: You could try putting an IBOutlet in your view controller, and then wire the button from BeginingCell.xib to the outlet in your view controller. Also have an IBAction in your view controller, which you wire from the xib.

Comment: i tried declaring a IBOutlet in the TavleView Controller.But same here.No response.I am not getting a proper solution.Can you please give me a proper guideline?

Comment: :D...finally it's done...actually there was a UIView under the controls...so it wasn't responding...

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically add an action to the UIButton using the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method (a method of UIControl, of which UIButton is a subclass).

So your implementation would look something like:

```
[ansBtn1 addTarget:self
             action:@selector(btnAction)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

          [ansBtn1 addTarget:self
             action:@selector(btnAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}
//Buttons Action
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender
{

}
```

Comment: Where should i put this code?In the BeginingCell(CustomCell) implementation or in the tablViewImplementation?

Comment: In BeginingCell class's initWithStyle function ... Just use as written in my answer ..

Comment: i put the code like ://Buttons Action
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender
{
 NSLog(@"test");

}





///########### Factory ///###########

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
 
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
  
  [ansBtn1 addTarget:self
     action:@selector(btnAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
} but nothing happening.I tested by debugging.

Comment: it's not even reaching the method :initWithStyle